# Triggering an event if dropdown list changed

Tags: asp.net, dropdownbox

I have a web page in asp.net that when a button is clicked a panel appears using the modalpopeup ajox tool.

On this panel I have 3 other panels and only the first one is visible.  On this panel is a dropdownbox which when changed I want to either display the second or third panel depending on the option selected.  I have read on other posts to add in the following text

`AutoPostBack="true"`

This obviously causes the page to reload making my original panel vanish therefore ruining the effect.

Are there any other techniques I could use to achieve the result I desire.

I am using VS2013 and VB.  I can post my code but its very messy at the moment as I am just making a prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `UpdatePanel` UpdateMode set as `conditional` with ASP.Net AJAX

or use jQuery Ajax

like

```
$.ajax({ajaxsetups;});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the selectedIndex changed event of dropdown